# Drawer not working with Typescript - material-ui v1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using material-ui@1.0.0-beta.37 and typescript@2.7.2. I'm trying to use the Drawer component to create a side navigation bar, but I'm getting the following compilation error from Typescript:

```
(21,9): Property 'onClose' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Drawer> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<DrawerProps>'.
```

I've checked the material-ui types and onClose seems to come from the ModalProps, which is part of DrawerProps. Do I need to do something to use the material-ui types correctly?

Here is my SideNav component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Drawer from 'material-ui/Drawer';
import { MenuItem } from 'material-ui/Menu';

export interface SideNavStateProps {
  isOpen: boolean;
}

export interface SideNavDispatchProps {
  toggleDrawer: () => void;
}

export interface SideNavProps extends SideNavStateProps, SideNavDispatchProps {}

class SideNav extends React.Component<SideNavProps, any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
        open={this.props.isOpen}
        docked={false}
        onClose={this.props.toggleDrawer}
      >
        <MenuItem>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>Meal Plans</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
}

export default SideNav;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was upgrading from the old version of material-ui. It turns out I had `@types/material-ui` installed for the old version. So the error was because typescript was using the wrong type definitions. Once I removed those old type definitions, everything started working correctly.